# Is there a better way to swap an img for another img on hover in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use a simple bootstrap img-circle class and swap it for another image on hover. I would like a simple solution to this while still maintaining the bootstrap classes to keep the images in a circle.

**Is there a better way to swap images on hover while still maintaining the bootstrap classes?**

```css
.circle {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<img class="img-circle circle" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/400">

<img class="img-circle circle" src="http://placekitten.com/g/210/400">
```

Here's a fiddle, note I'm extremely new to bootstrap, and I'm just looking for the best solution to this answer. Thank you all!

https://jsfiddle.net/vvyt6cyt/

Comment: A better way than what? You haven't described _any_ way of swapping the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo-class `:hover` to change the `background-image` property on your `circle` class.

Working kitty fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/vvyt6cyt/3/

CSS:

```
.circle:hover {
  background-image: url('your-kitty-url-here')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper for your `img` and make that hoverable via CSS. Then you can swap images by changing the `display` property.

For example:

## HTML

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="img-circle circle" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/400">
    <img class="img-circle circle" src="http://placekitten.com/g/210/400">
</div>
```

## CSS

```
/* Display first image */
.image-wrapper > :first-child(){
    display: block;
}

.image-wrapper > :nth-child(2){
    display: none;
}

/* Display second image */
.image-wrapper:hover > :first-child(){
    display: none;
}

.image-wrapper:hover > :nth-child(2){
    display: block;
}
```

I would try and change your implementation to use `background-image` instead. Take a look **[background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)**, but that's all up to you :)

Any questions? Ask on the comments below.

Comment: Similar, with changing `z-index` in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvyt6cyt/4/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a single image tag with a background.

On hover reset size and padding :

```css
.circle {height:350px; width:350px;}
.swap {
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/210/400);
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
.swap:hover {
  height:0;
  width:0;
  padding:175px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<img class="img-circle circle swap" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/400">
```

A few example using transition for different effects : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Joqzp